# I want to get the ID from all TR Tag in Table and concat it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to get all ID from the `TR` tags in a string and add a pipe between the IDs.

```js
var files = "";

$('#list_files tr').each(function() {
  if (files == "") {
    files = files.concat($(this).attr("id"));
  } else {
    files = files.concat("|" & $(this).attr("id"));
  }
})

console.log(files);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="list_files">
  <tr id="ID-1">
    <td>value-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="ID-2">
    <td>value-2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="ID-3">
    <td>value-3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

At the end I want to get this "ID-1|ID-2|ID-3"

Now I get this in string "ID-100" he adds 2 zeros but I don't know why

Comment: `&` is not the operator to concatenate two strings (and `.concat()` is at least unusual)

Comment: _"Now i get this in string "ID-100" he adds 2 zeros but i dont know why"_ - Because you use the wrong operator.

Comment: @Andreas yes you right thank you  my hero, i didnt see it the whole time xD thanks VB

Comment: If you're going to use `.concat` then `files = files.concat("|"); files = files.concat($(this).attr("id"))`

Comment: `$('#list_files tr').map((_, tr) => tr.id).get().join("|")`

Comment: You should try '+' in place of '&' in here "files = files.concat("|" & $(this).attr("id"))"

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
var files = "";

$('#list_files tr').each(function() {
    if($(this).is(":last-child"))
    {
        files += $(this).attr("id");
    }
    else
    {
        files += $(this).attr("id") + "" + "|";
    }
})

console.log(files);
```